# Execute Gradle task when compile project in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

Few modules in my Spring Boot web application(database, paymet). I need to Execute a gradle task, when compile the database module. I tried it in below way but it gives errors.

```
dependencies {
 compile project(':pathToDatabaseModule') {
    dependsOn('taskName')
 }
}
```

My task is to copy specific set of files.

```
task taskName(type: Copy) {
 from "${rootDir}/fromPath"
 into "${rootDir}/toPath"
}
```

It gives following error,

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'dependsOn()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'intersureplus' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.2 and sync project</li><li>The project 'intersureplus' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file</li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin</li>
```

All the things are correct, error comes when I add the **dependsOn** inside **compile** block like above. I am beginner to the gradle, so please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: can you decribed more in details what you try to achieve?  what task do you need to execute (what is it doing? ) , when exactly you need this task to be executed? (before which task from the root project).

Comment: I added more explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dependsOn` method is exposed by `Task` class in Gradle, you cannot use this method anywhere in your script, and certainly not in the `dependencies` configuration block. If you want to create a dependency between a task from your root project (example: `build` task) and a task defined in sub-project `:projectpath` (for example: `dependenTask` task) , then you can write something like that in your root project's `build.gradle`script:

```
build.dependsOn(':projectpath:dependenTask')
```

which is equivalent to :

```
project.tasks.getByName('build').dependsOn(':projectpath:dependenTask')
```

**EDIT** You can also create a dependency in the other direction: make a task from *database* subproject depend on a "pre-processing" task defined in the root project:

in **/database/build.gradle**  script:

```
tasks.getByName('build').dependsOn(':preProcessTask')
```

Comment: I could fix this problem by adding below block in database/build.gradle,

Comment: **database/build.gradle**, 'tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    dependsOn "taskName"
}'

Comment: yes it's another way to reference a Task,  by type instead of name. glad it worked.